# Why is BStrWrapper only required for C# application?

Tags: c#, com, solidworks

In the SOLIDWORKS API documentation, it is explicitly stated that in order to marshal an array of .NET strings back SOLIDWORKS, you must use the [BStrWrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.bstrwrapper?view=netframework-4.7.2) class. It also states this for C# applications without the mention of VB.NET? Is there a reason for that? Thank you.

[Source](http://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IPackAndGo~RemoveExternalDocuments.html)

[image]

Comment: If you want to know why a particular API documentation says what it does, the correct people to ask would be the people who wrote that documentation.

Comment: No, considerations are the exact same in vb.net.  Actually needing to do this is extremely uncommon, it just doesn't make much sense to pass a string array with a null element.  This should have been fixed in SolidWorks itself, there is probably an old bug report for it.  But not uncommonly for code written over a decade ago, there probably isn't anybody around anymore that still knows how it works or dares touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with VB.net but I think this is because of different casting rules in C# and VB.NET.
Underneath, the method you referenced looks (in C++):

```
virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_RemoveExternalDocuments (
        /*[in]*/ VARIANT DocumentNames,
        /*[out,retval]*/ VARIANT_BOOL * Retval ) = 0;
```

Or better looking:

```
VARIANT_BOOL RemoveExternalDocuments (const _variant_t & DocumentNames );
```

C# requires using BStrWrapper because it marshals string as VARIANT, [see MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.bstrwrapper?view=netframework-4.7.2). And it looks VB.NET can do it implicit.

Comment: I'm pretty comfortable with this answer so I am going to check it. When you say "it looks VB.NET can do it implicit.", do you mean that because there is no mention of VB.NET in the link you posted?

Comment: I checked both examples in SOLIDWORKS API documentation for C# and VB.NET. VB.NET example work fine without BStrWrapper. So this why I concluded regarding implicit type casting (marshaling).